# Spot 5 Syntactic errors in this BPMN Diagram

Tags: bpmn, parallels

[image: A BPMN Diagram with 5 Syntactic errors]

The only Syntactic error I can find here is Complete Transaction should be closed. I also have not understood "Parallel" pathway. I am also confused as why there is a "+" symbol for every procedure. The book isn't simply great. Please kindly tell me the errors with full clarification.

Answer (score 0):

1.Service Label is absent.

2.Reserved from stock must be in “Finance”

3.From “Status” to “Order car from factory”, “Order from factory” step description is missing.

4.After “Handle Cancellation”, the description “Reason?” is missing and lastly no feedback message

Answer (score 0):

End-state "Transaction complete" uses the None start event graphic.

Comment: Could you give more details ?